# Drupal 8 - Node reference migrate to entity reference type

Tags: drupal, migration, drupal-8, migrate

I try to migrate drupal 7 site to version 8 following this steps https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/upgrade/upgrading-from-drupal-6-or-7-to-drupal-8. But when migrate the fields of content types I get error of this type in fields that reference other content types "Attempt to create a [field_name] with no type.". "upgrade_d7_field" is the migration id I execute. I'm doing the migration via drush.

I know the posible problem, but I dont know how to resolve. In drupal 7 the type of fields that reference other content types is the "Node reference" type, but in version 8 that type doesn't exist anymore, now is of type "entity reference".

I think that I should change some configurations in my migration definition but I don't know exactly what.

This is migration definition of the migration id "upgrade_d7_field":

```
uuid: 2edaccb2-22a6-4482-895f-439bbbc66f1a
langcode: es
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: upgrade_d7_field
class: Drupal\migrate_drupal\Plugin\migrate\FieldMigration
field_plugin_method: alterFieldMigration
cck_plugin_method: null
migration_tags:
  - 'Drupal 7'
  - Configuration
migration_group: migrate_drupal_7
label: 'Field configuration'
source:
  plugin: d7_field
  constants:
    status: true
    langcode: und
process:
  entity_type:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: entity_type
  status:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: constants/status
  langcode:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: constants/langcode
  field_name:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: field_name
  type:
    -
      plugin: process_field
      source: type
      method: getFieldType
      map:
        d7_text:
          d7_text: d7_text
        taxonomy_term_reference:
          taxonomy_term_reference: taxonomy_term_reference
        image:
          image: image
        link_field:
          link_field: link_field
        file:
          file: file
        datetime:
          datetime: datetime
        list:
          list: list
  cardinality:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: cardinality
  settings:
    -
      plugin: d7_field_settings
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:field_storage_config'
migration_dependencies:
  required: {  }
  optional: {  }
```

Seriously I need migrate the data of the D7 site, they are more than 17.000 news with taxonomies, comments and more.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are using the [References](https://www.drupal.org/project/references) module that provides D7 versions of the `node_reference` and `user_reference` field types from the old CCK package.

This module was the solution to get these field types enabled in the early days of drupal 7.

Some time later, [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) cames out to d7, it provides a generic field type to reference arbitrary entities and has been included with Drupal 8 core since then.

To address your issue, you should start by migrating the reference fields into the proper field type `entity_reference`.

There is a module called [Reference to EntityReference Field Migration](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_migration) that should help get the job done before your drupal 8 migration.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to try it. Do you think that this will also help me to migrate the fields of the video type, which use the video module embed field??.

Comment: I don't think you need an entity reference for this (unless you have 'video' entity type?). The video module has a d8 version so I assume it provides support for migrating data, that said the project page explicitly mentions that "*embed video to node body using WYSIWYG module is d7 only*". If your concern is about displaying embedded videos, you may look at this [example](https://github.com/heshanlk/Video-Provider-YouTube-Example) and at the available field widgets in the d8 version.

Comment: I have already migrated everything I needed. Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

lets assume the d7 field is on a content type called `publications` and the field is, **field_articles_d7** referencing a content type called `articles` and the new D8 entity reference field is called **field_articles_d8** (assume this is on the same content type called `publications`)also referencing the content type called `articles`

The sequence should be to

- Migrate the `article` content type  (migration id : d7_node_article)
- Then Migrate the `publications` node type (migration id : d7_node_publication)

  - In the process section you need to do this

    - ```
              field_articles_d8:
                  plugin: migration_lookup
                  migration: d7_node_article
                  source: field_articles_d7
      ```

This is usually the sequential process of migrating a Node reference in Drupal 7 to a Entity Reference in Drupal 8